# Implicit declaration of function loop1 and loop2

Tags: c

The errors I get on `loop1` and `loop2` are:

> data definition has no type or storage class

and

> Implicit declaration of function `loop1` and `loop2`

Also can anyone show me a while loop version of this code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int a[5] = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 };
int x, temp, size = 5;

int main()
{
    printf("BEFORE: \n\n");
    for (x = 0; x = 4; x++)
    {
        printf("Element [%d] is %d\n"), x, a[x];
    }
    loop1();
    printf("n==============\nAFTER:\n\n");
    loop2();
}

loop1();
{
    for (x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
    {
        temp = a[x];
        a[x];
        a[(size - 1) - x] = temp;
   }
}

loop2();
{
    for (x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
    {
        printf("Element [%d] is %d\n"), x, a[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- Please adopt some decent code style and _use it_! Your code is barely readable, I have tidied it a bit. -- The message is clear: You did not provide a prototype for the called functions. -- The definition of the functions is syntactically wrong. Please consult your C book or script how to do this right.

Comment: This is dupe question +100. Just move `main` below the two functions or add proto types for the functions before `main`

Comment: `for (x = 0; x = 4; x++)` --> `for (x = 0; x != 4; x++)`

Comment: Are you reading a C book from 1984?

Comment: In your function definitions, you should include explicit return types and parameter list and omit the trailing semi-colon.  eg `void loop2(void) { ... }`

Comment: `printf("Element [%d] is %d\n"), x, a[x];` hmm... the arguments are place outside the function call

Comment: `loop1();` hmm... what is that `;` doing there !? And why is there no return type?

Comment: `a[x];` hmmm... what do you exppect this to do?

Answer (score 1):

I did not try to debug your code. This is the correct definition of the functions syntactically. Based on what you need them to do, you should pass also parameters in. But, the program does not run logically correctly, you should find the problem and tell us the expected output in order to help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[5] = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 };
int x, temp, size = 5;


void loop1()
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
    {
        temp = a[x];
        a[x];
        a[(size - 1) - x] = temp;
   }
}

void loop2()
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
    {
        printf("Element [%d] is %d\n"), x, a[x];
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("BEFORE: \n\n");
    for (x = 0; x = 4; x++)
    {
        printf("Element [%d] is %d\n"), x, a[x];
    }
    loop1();
    printf("n==============\nAFTER:\n\n");
    loop2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many bugs in your program. To mention a few: Functions called before being declared. Arguments placed outside functions calls. Statement that doesn't do anything. Assignment instead of condition. Etc...

Try like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[5] = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 };
int x, temp, size = 5;

void loop1()
{
    for (x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
    {
        temp = a[x];
        //a[x];  ???? why...
        a[(size - 1) - x] = temp;
   }
}

void loop2()
{
    for (x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
    {
        printf("Element [%d] is %d\n", x, a[x]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("BEFORE: \n\n");
    for (x = 0; x != 4; x++)
    {
        printf("Element [%d] is %d\n", x, a[x]);
    }
    loop1();
    printf("n==============\nAFTER:\n\n");
    loop2();
}
```

BTW:

You need to turn up your compilers warning level.

For instance: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror ...`